# Whose property is user-created homebrew material on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, publishing, intellectual-property, dnd-beyond

When creating homebrew material on [D&D Beyond (dndbeyond.com)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/), what kind of license do I grant to Fandom Games for the material that I create by using its tools? Or more broadly, whose property is that user-created material?

Comment: Related from the Curse/Twitch days: [What kind of license or ownership does uploading content to D&D Beyond grant WOTC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108152/52137)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## All Community Creations on Fandom sites use CC-BY-SA 3.0

*Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. I am merely going by the information gatherable. The advice of random people on the internet does not constitute legal advice, especially this idiot.*

The Terms of Service link on the bottom of all pages on D&D Beyond goes to Fandom's [Terms of Use](https://www.fandom.com/terms-of-use) page. Those terms of use include their [licensing terms](https://www.fandom.com/licensing) which state:

> Except where otherwise permitted, the text on Fandom communities (known as “wikis”) is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike License 3.0 (Unported) (CC-BY-SA).

You can find a human readable summary of that licence [here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) ([or a lawyer readable here](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode)). As I understand it (again, I am not a lawyer), content written by you is owned by you, but you have licensed anyone to share it freely and adapt and iterate upon it, as long as they attribute you as the original author and that iterations are under the same license.

Comment: The specific [homebrew rules and guidelines can also be found here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew-rules-guidelines); they don't mention anything about copyright, and also reference Fandom's Terms of Use. That said, does D&D Beyond/its homebrew system really fit the description of "Fandom communities (known as “wikis”)"?

Comment: @V2Blast I don't see how D&D Beyond could possibly fall under "Fandom communities (known as "wikis")". I wonder what the Terms of Use said before Fandom acquired Curse?

Comment: I think there is room for improvement, but this answer is helpful and thus I will accept it.

Comment: @Akixkisu Room for improvement in the answer, or in D&D Beyond's statement/clarify on the matter?

Comment: @Someone_Evil it is a great answer, clarifying the issue of property (by discerning the linked licence) would make it an excellent answer.

Comment: @Akixkisu Are there specific additions you would like to see beyond what is given after the link in the last paragraph? "content written by you is owned by you, but you have licensed anyone to share it freely and adapt and iterate upon it"

Comment: @Someone_Evil I think that would be ideal. I don't think anything else would add much more.